# Display image when button is clicked Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, image-processing, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application using PySimpleGUI.

So far my UI looks like this:[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZUGp.png)
As you can see, the user has to click on browse to select the folder of the images after which the filenames of all the images in that folder will be displayed inside the section below it. The user can click on any of the image. After clicking on any of the filename, image will be displayed on the white window.

[This is how image is selected and displayed on the white window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLLiH.png)

Now what I want is when I click on normalize button, the original image should be forwarded to the normalise function and the output image should be replaced by the normalized image.

```
def normalise(image, frame):
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(image)
    equ=update_image(image)
    return equ



def update_listbox(listbox_element, folder, extension, substring):
    path = Path(folder)
    filter_ = substring.lower()
    lst = []
    if folder != '' and path.is_dir():
        files = list(path.glob("*.*"))
        lst = [file for file in files if file.suffix.lower() in extension
            and filter_ in str(file).lower() and file.is_file()]
    listbox_element.update(lst)


def update_image(image_element, filename):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    w, h = size_of_image
    scale = max(im.width/w, im.height/h)
    if scale <= 1:
        image_element.update(filename=filename)
        return im
    else:
        im = im.resize((int(im.width/scale), int(im.height/scale)),
            resample=Image.CUBIC)
        with BytesIO() as output:
            im.save(output, format="PNG")
            im = output.getvalue()
        image_element.update(data=im)

    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)


if __name__ == '__main__':


sg.theme('Dark')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 11))

    w, h = size_of_image = (700, 600)

    layout_top = [
        [sg.InputText(enable_events=True, key='-FOLDER-'),
        sg.FolderBrowse('Browse', size=(7, 1), enable_events=True)],
        [sg.InputText(enable_events=True, key='-FILTER-'),
        sg.Button('Search', size=(7, 1))],[sg.Listbox([], size=(45, 10), enable_events=True,
            select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE, key='-LISTBOX-')],
    ]

    layout_bottom = [
    [sg.Button('Normalize', size=(20, 1),enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Button('Enhance', size=(20, 1))], [sg.Button('Preprocess', size=(20, 1))],
    [sg.Button('Binarization', size=(20, 1))], [sg.Button('Thinning', size=(20, 1))],
    [sg.Button('Singular Points', size=(20, 1))], [sg.Button('Minutiae', size=(20, 1))],
    [sg.Button('Classify', size=(20, 1))], [sg.Button('Match', size=(20, 1))],
        ]
    layout_left = [
        [sg.Column(layout_top, pad=(0, 0))],
        [sg.Column(layout_bottom, pad=(0, 0))],
    ]

    layout_right = [[sg.Image(background_color='white', key='im')],[sg.Button('NEXT', size= 
   (20, 1),pad=(300,10))]]

    layout = [
        [sg.Column(layout_left), sg.Column(layout_right, pad=(0, 0), size=(w+15, h+15), 
background_color='lightblue', key='-COLUMN-')],

    ]

    window = sg.Window("PNG/GIF Viewer", layout, finalize=True)
    window['im'].Widget.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    window['im'].Widget.master.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    window['im'].Widget.master.master.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    window['-COLUMN-'].Widget.pack_propagate(0)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
# print(event, values)
        if event in ('-FOLDER-', '-FILTER-', 'Search'):
            update_listbox(window['-LISTBOX-'], values['-FOLDER-'],
                ('.png', '.gif'), values['-FILTER-'])
        elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
            lst = values['-LISTBOX-']
            if lst != []:
                im=update_image(window['im'], values['-LISTBOX-'][0])

                if event == 'normalize':

                    normalise(im, window['im'])


    window.close()
```

The code above works fine till displaying the original image but what I want is after displaying the original image, the function returns the image and when user clicks on normalize, the image is passed to 'normalise function' and then the original image is replaced with the new image.

This part is not working. I dont know what am I doing wrong. Since I am new to UI in python, I find it hard to identify my problem.

```
if event == 'normalize':
 normalise(im, window['im'])
```

Since I have written the backend code on colab, it is tested so there is no error on the backend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can `event` is `'-LISTBOX-'` and `event` is `'normalize'` ?
So the statement `normalize(im, windo['im']) won't be executed all the time.

```py
        elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
            lst = values['-LISTBOX-']
            if lst != []:
                im=update_image(window['im'], values['-LISTBOX-'][0])
                if event == 'normalize':
                    normalise(im, window['im'])
```

Not look detail of your code, maybe your code should like this,

```py
    im = None
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event in ('-FOLDER-', '-FILTER-', 'Search'):
            update_listbox(window['-LISTBOX-'], values['-FOLDER-'],
                ('.png', '.gif'), values['-FILTER-'])
        elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
            lst = values['-LISTBOX-']
            if lst != []:
                im=update_image(window['im'], values['-LISTBOX-'][0])
        elif event == 'normalize':
            if im:
                normalise(im, window['im'])
    window.close()
```

Comment: `im` is not defined if you click `'normalize'` button first, to avoid error, it need to be defined as `None` or something when initialize.

Comment: I followed your code. It removed the previous code but it is now giving error for:

line 15, in normalise
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(image)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: You need to check format of `im` which should be `8-bit single channel image` for `cv2.equalizeHist`. Another question is your function `update_image` may return different object, maybe `im` or `ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)`

Comment: Before you wrote the previous comment, I had already changed the image object to an array and it worked. Thank you so much for the detailed guidance. It works perfectly now.